# How to use Karma test this.nav.push and this.menu.enable in ionic2

Tags: unit-testing, navbar, ionic2

I'm new in Karma and ionic 2. Now I need to test the login file. There are two functions below and is there anyone know how to test them?

```
  onSignup() {
    this.nav.push(SignupPage);
  }
```

and the following function is used to know the page changed

```
  onPageDidEnter() {
    // the root left menu should be disabled on the tutorial page
    console.log("enter login");
    console.log("login"+JSON.stringify(this.nav));
    console.log(this.nav.length());
    this.menu.enable(false);
  }

  onPageWillLeave() {
    // enable the root left menu when leaving the tutorial page
    console.info("out login");
    this.menu.enable(false);
  }
```

**The class and export:**

```
export class LoginPage implements OnInit{

login: {username?: string, password?: string} = {};  
submitted :boolean = false;
  //let user ="";
  //let pass ="";private userData: UserData, 
  constructor(private nav: NavController,
              private menu : MenuController,
              private loginProvider : LoginProvider) {}
```

Anyone know how to test these code? Because when I just call this function and want to test as this:

```
expect(logins.onSignup()).toHaveBeenCalled(true);
```

**error**

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.nav.push')
```

Comment: I'm wondering if you got this to work? I also need to test the push method but I don't know how to mock it

Answer (score -1):

This is the mock of how you can test it with `Karma` and `Jasmine`. For more on testing you can check out angular [`TestBed`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#testing-intro).

```
let component = fixture.component;
spyOn(component.nav.push).and.stub();
component.onSignup();
expect(component.nav.push).toHaveBeenCalledWith(SignupPage);
```

Comment: Getting error : Error: <spyOn> : push() method does not exist, this is my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49588124/jasmine-karma-how-to-check-navigation-functionality-in-ionic